# Difference in way of proving [0,1] is uncountable, (0,1) is uncountable, and etc

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a proof for $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

Proof: Suppose $[0,1]$ is countable. then there exists a surjection $f:\mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$.

Since $0. \bar9  = 1$ and any terminating decimal can be completed with an infinite string of $0$, for $n  \in \mathbb{N}$, represent $f(n)$ as $0.d_1 ^n d_2 ^n d_3 ^n$........

Now let y be the real number represented by $0.a_1a_2a_3$...... represented by where

$$a_n =3 \;\;\text{if} \;\;d_n^n \neq 3$$ 
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;4 \;\;\;\text{if} \;\;d_n^n = 3 $$

Then for all $n  \in \mathbb{N}, y \neq f(n)$

Since the $n$-th decimal of $y$ and $f(n)$ do not agree. So $y$ is not in the image of $f$ and $f$ is not surjective.

Let's say I want to use this similar process to prove $(0,1), [0,1)$ or $(0,1)$ is uncountable. What would be the difference in the process of proving these?

Can I just use the same process? or should there be a slight difference?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the removal of one or two points would render an uncountable set countable!

Comment: Well, there is an obvious bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[\frac14,\frac34]$; so $[\frac14,\frac34]$ is uncountable. But $[\frac14,\frac34]$ is a subset of $(0,1)$. That is enough to prove $(0,1)$ uncountable. So it's a waste of effort to use diagonalisation here.

Comment: oh i see... thanks so much!

Comment: How about proving [a,b] is uncountable? Do i find a bijection [a,b] -> [0,1] ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

The only reason why the same process might not work again is that your number $y$ might end up outside the set.  For example, if you had instead used

$$a_n =0 \;\;\text{if} \;\;d_n^n \neq 0$$ 
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;1 \;\;\;\text{if} \;\;d_n^n = 0 $$

then you'd run into problems showing that $(0,1)$ was uncountable because then $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$ might not be contained in $(0,1)$, *even if $f(n)\in(0,1)$ for all $n$.  For example, setting $f_n=10^{-n}$, we get $d_n^n=1$ for each $n$, so $a_n=0$ for each $n$ and then $0.a_1a_2\dots=0\not\in(0,1)$.

However, the way you've done it (with $3$s and $4$s) prevents anything like that happening, so you should be fine using the same proof again.

Note that $[0,1],[0,1),(0,1],(0,1)$ are all infinite sets that differ from one another by finite sets so they all have the same cardinality.  Thus, once you have proved that $[0,1]$ is uncountable, you don't need to use the diagonal argument again to prove that the others are uncountable.